can I add a local group to selected LDAP users?
I've a typo3 11.5.41 with LDAP extension 3.8.0
The LDAP configuration assigns a local Group to all the FE users, but I like to pick some of them and individually assign to them also a second local group.
If I go to the typo3 list module, select the LDAP users folder and search for a user record, I can edit it, adding the second group and I can successfully save all the work.
Sadly, the first time the user logs in my site, this added group in his record is destroyed and remains only the default local group assigned by LDAP! :=)
Is it a way to bypass this and maintain also the second group?
Thanks in advance for your reply,
Fabiano

There are several hooks/events for modifying the received data: https://docs.typo3.org/p/causal/ig_ldap_sso_auth/main/en-us/Development/Index.html

In LocalConfiguration.php, set keepFEGroups to 1.
This option allows you to keep locally assigned frontend groups.
'ig_ldap_sso_auth' => [
    'keepFEGroups' => '1'
],


Thanks a lot!! :=)
Take Care,
Fabiano
